# Is there an MbUnit equivalent in Java?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mbunit

Specifically, I am looking for the same ease of defining parameterized and combinatorial unit tests.

Thanks.

P.S.

Please, do not suggest JUnit. Its parameterized and theory features do not even reach the ancles of the respective features in MbUnit.

**EDIT**

Here is a very short description of the features of MbUnit that I would like to have in java:

1. FactoryAttribute - allows to get parameters from a method or property at run-time.
2. RowAttribute - allows to get compile time parameters to all of the parameters of the test.
3. ColumnAttribute - allows to get compile time parameters to a specific parameter.

Mixing and matching the Factory and Column attributes allows to create combinatorial tests easily. The Factory attribute can be attached to the test method itself or to the indvidual parameters.

In addition, the test method can be generic and the output produced by the Factory method can be fed into that parameter as well, making it possible to use different generic type argument for different test iterations.

Comment: Could you say which specific features of MbUnit you're looking for?

Comment: It would be trivial to implement this so I'd imagine it's been done somewhere, have you tried looking into the various mock libraries.   I've always done stuff like this by generating simple junit test code from the data model.

Comment: If you can't find any library which already does that, implementing yourself a custom JUnit runner which does that isn't too hard - a couple of hours of work for an initial version.